# .htaccess multi subfolder redirection based on URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect the request to the corresponding file using httaccess for multiple subfolders.

**For example (GOAL):**

1) www.mysite.com -> /var/www/mysite/website/index.php

2) www.mysite.com/app -> /var/www/mysite/app/web/index.php

3) www.mysite.com/app2 -> /var/www/mysite/app2/web/index.php

With the following piece of code i can achieve step 2 for example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../app/web/$1 [L]
```

but if i add for example..

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/website/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/$1 [L]
```

1) works great, but 2) stop working... obviously the second piece of code override the first.. but i don't know how to deal with this.

If there is an answer with easy understanding and / or with easy implementation about this goal in particular i don't found it.

can anyone share an example of how can achieve step 1 and step 2 together? or even if it is inpossible and the only way is using the "category" (app, app2, website) in all cases in the url.

any help is thankful

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^/?$ website/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/.*)?$ /$1/web$2 [L]
```

Comment: At this point:
1) www.mysite.com/app -> works 

 //
2) www.mysite.com -> dont work.

Its displaying in my screen the same message as i say in the third comment

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check for `HTTP_HOST`, because all requests will match. You also don't need to check for `REQUEST_URI`, because you can do that in the pattern part of the [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). For the rest, you can just use easy, specific rules

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^app2 /app2/web/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^app /app/web/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /website/index.php [L]
```

You must pay attention to the order of the rules. If `app` were first, it would also match `app2`. These rules assume, that the document root is in `/var/www/mysite`. If it is in `/var/www`, you must prefix the substitution with `/mysite`, e.g. `/mysite/app2/web/index.php`, etc.

Comment: The rules aren't working.. i think i missed something, my file structure is ok.